# Correct way to get a gRPC client to communicate with one of many ECS instances of the gRPC service?

Tags: grpc, amazon-ecs

I have a gRPC client, not dockerised, and server application, which I want to dockerise.

What I don't understand is that gRPC first creates a connection with a server, which involves a handshake. So, if I want to deploy the dockerised server on ECS with multiple instances, then how will the client switch from one to the other (e.g., if one gRPC server falls over).

I know AWS loadbalancer now works with HTTP 2, but I can't find information on how to handle the fact that the server might change after the client has already opened a connection to another one.

What is involved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't necessarily need an in-line load balancer for this. By using a [Round Robin client-side load balancing policy](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/2d4f3c56001cd1e1f85734b2f7c5ce5f2797c38a/doc/load-balancing.md) along with a DNS record that points to multiple backend instances, you should be able to get some level of redundancy.